# MSI package keeps uninstalling - why?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6, bootstrapper, burn

I've defined the following MSIPackage in a chain ([Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) 3.6).

```
<!-- DacFramework x86-->
<MsiPackage
    Id="msi_DacFramework"
    SourceFile="..\..\External References\MSI\Microsoft\SSDT\DacFramework\11.1.2825.1.May2013\x86\DACFramework.msi"
    InstallCondition="(VersionNT64) OR (NOT VersionNT64)"
    DownloadUrl="http://ourURL.com/updates/x86/DACFramework.msi"
    Compressed="no"
    Vital="yes"
    Permanent="yes"
    SuppressSignatureVerification="yes"
    Visible="yes"/>
```

To my understanding, making it *Vital* and *Permanent* should mean it keeps installs on an upgrade to our product - the MSI in question is an [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) component that comes from Microsoft, so we're not going to be changing it. The *InstallCondition* should also return True.

As you can guess from the title however, it *IS* being uninstalled when our product gets upgraded. From the log, it seems as if it is being asked to.. (REMOVE=ALL)

```
MSI (s) (D0:18) [17:03:04:781]: Command Line: MSIFASTINSTALL=7 REBOOT=ReallySuppress IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL REMOVE=ALL CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Program Files\CompanyName\Product CLIENTUILEVEL=3 CLIENTPROCESSID=4004
...
MSI (s) (D0:18) [17:03:04:781]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding REMOVE property. Its value is 'ALL'.
```

What have I missed in the MSIPackage definition in order to think it's being asked to REMOVE?

Comment: So your upgrade package doesnt have your DACFramework.msi?

Comment: Hi Isaiah4110 unsure what you mean. The dacFramework.msi was downloaded if and when required, but ultimately I never got to the bottom of this and removed it altogether from our standard update stream, and put it in a separate pre-requisites install, so thereby removing it altogether from our own updates - it's an MS MSi after all, which should change infrequently.